# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html : JSONP

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp, mime-types, mime

In the following code, I get the error: [***JSFIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/k2akLvd4/4/)

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://cob.cdcs.selu.edu/WEB-APP/VBF-Directory2/api/all.php?callback=?",
    async : false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log("Log :" + data);
});
```

Forgive me for being new with JSONP. I even looked up various resources on Stackoverflow and w3. I could not still figure out.

In the php file `$array` is an array and the only code that prints is:,

```
 echo json_ecode($array)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my research, JSONP is not JSON. It actually should be JavaScript, and you need to wrap your results in the callback function call (`callbackName(data);`)

```
<?= $_GET['callback'] ?>(<?= jsonResult ?>);
```